# Full uninstall firefox nightly

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I tried a lot of commands to remove firefox, but when I install again, profiles continue on computer, but the problem aren't the profiles, the problem is some rendering problems, I can't see the link I'm surfing and I can't see tabs either.

I tried: `sudo apt-get purge firefox-trunk` and `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove firefox` but it doesn't work.

[image: Firefox nightly issues]

Comment: Have you also removed the package repositories / PPA provided with Firefox installations? If not, Nightly will be installed from there over and over again.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "profiles continue on computer"?

Comment: The profile with all history and bookmarks.. How to remove ppa?

Comment: For profile, it is probably not about software files. As I know, browser's storage their settings/profile files in somewhere else and if you find & delete them, you won't need to re-install the software.
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Linux
Try to look from here and clean those folder. That should do the trick to remove your profiles.

Comment: Fresh install problem presist, so its a bug!

Comment: A fresh install of what? Firefox?

Comment: Fresh install of elementary and firefox beta and nightly, nightly still the same, stable looks perfect

Answer (score 2):

You probably added the [official PPA for Firefox Beta](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next) to your repositories. In order to switch back to Firefox stable, you need to remove this PPA again.

Start *Software Updater* and click at *Settings*, now switch to the tab *Other Software* and search for the following lines:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu trusty main 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu trusty main (Source Code)
```

Uncheck or remove these lines and close the *Software Updater*.

[image: PPA Settings]

To get the current stable version of Firefox, uninstall and install Firefox again. If you are using the terminal to install Firefox, please run `sudo apt-get update` first.

If there are still problems, you probably gonna need to delete the previous Firefox profile.

Close *Firefox* and open *Files*, go to your *Home* folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display hidden files. Now delete the folder `.mozilla`, which contains your Firefox profile.

**You are going to delete your whole Firefox settings, extensions, bookmarks and browsing history!**

[image: Firefox profile]